# SSIS: "Access to the path ':Z\zfilepath' is denied."

Tags: ssis

I am having trouble moving a folder from an online drive, Drive :Z\zfilepath

to my local drive, Drive C:\cfilepath

So far, I have one 'file system task' that can copy a file from a source and move it to a destination.

[image: System File Task Editor]

I have correctly specified both filepaths and folder names into the task.

When I run the package, I get the following error:

[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path ':Z\zfilepath' is denied.".

Is there some way for me to set up the package such that it will have the credentials to access the online :Z\ drive and run the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z is likely a mapped drive. A drive is mapped per user account so the probable error is that the account that runs SQL Agent (or the credentialed user running a task) does not have that same drive mapped.

One maps a drive from the command line (Execute process task) with the following syntax

```
net use z: \\server\share PasswordInClearTextHere /user:domain\user /persistent:yes
```

I don't know enough about your environment. Maybe a one-time activity of mapping the drive will suffice `/persistent:yes`.

We had an issue where we always had to re-establish the mount when the job ran but we couldn't be certain the previous job succeeded (which had a final step of tear down the mount). Attempting to mount a drive when one already exists will throw an error so you might need another Execute Process Task to delete a mapped drive if it already exists. We ended up with a batch script that would check to see if the mount existed. If it did, it would delete it first. Then it established the mount.

This batch script approach allowed the DBAs to secure the file with file system permissions. The job could access the batch script but we could not so they didn't have to worry about us having access to yet-another-account.

The other, far simpler approach is to not deal with mounting drives and instead just use the UNC path. *Assuming* you don't have to worry about presenting different credentials than the current user, it makes life much easier.

```
\\server\share\MyFile.123.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The UNC path did the trick.